# how to send message from backgroundjs to content script in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on chrome extension and I've stuck on a very specific part where backgroundjs is suppose to send a message to current active tab .

This is my manifest file

**manifest.json**

```
{
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "test",
     "description": "Some_Test",
     "version": "1.0",

     "background": {
     "page":  "background.html"
     },
     "content_scripts": [
         {
             "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
             "js": [ "content.js" ]
         }
     ],
     "permissions": [
     "background",
     "activeTab",
     "tabs",
     "http://*/*",
     "https://*/*"
     ],
     "browser_action": {
         "default_popup": "popup.html"
      }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id="read-button">Read</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function readObject(e) {
    console.log(chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().read());
}

document.getElementById('read-button').addEventListener('click', readObject);
```

**background.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```
function read() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "hello" }, function (response) {
            return response.farewell;
        });
    });
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log("hello");
      if (request.greeting == "hello")
          sendResponse({ farewell: "goodbye" });
  });
```

This is where the error is :

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "hello" }, function (response) {
            return response.farewell;
        });
```

[image]

It seems that I cannot access `tabs[0]` object or I am unable to understand the Array which it returns, because i want to access the active tab and `tabs[0]` simply means it is getting the first tab in the browser and not the active tab.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can only happen if the active window is the Developer Tools of the background page.

Just switch to a normal browser window when testing the extension or define `read()` function in popup.js and remove the background page altogether if it's not absolutely needed.